# Finding an orthogonal matrix $P$ of the quadric $3x^2+3z^2-4xy-8xz+4yz=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, orthogonality

> I am trying to find an orthogonal matrix $P$ of the quadric $3x^2+3z^2-4xy-8xz+4yz=1$.

I have found that the eigenvalues are $-1$ (with algebraic multiplicity 2) and $8$ (with algebraic multiplicity 1) with corresponding eigenvectors {<1,0,1>,<-0.5,-2,0.5>} and {<2,-1,-2>} respectively. I know, once normalised, that these eigenvectors form the columns of $P$, but must the $det(P)=1$? If so, my matrix $P$ is incorrect as I can't manipulate the eigenvectors to adhere to this property. This is a question from a past exam paper and help on this problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We just need to normalize the vectors by $$u_i=\frac{v_i}{|v_i|}$$

in order to obtain $P$ such that $P^TP=I$.

Comment: I have done this. Putting these orthonormal vectors as columns in the matrix $P$, I still don't get $det(P)=1$.

Comment: Could you show your work, I can check it.

Comment: I believe I found my mistake, thank you :)